# Ms Sql Insert with select

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is the SQL Query for Insert using Select , which is not working, Please Help with the Issue:

```
 insert into Area Values (AreaId, AreaName, Pincode, CityId, StateId, CountryId)
    select CityId
    from Area
      join City On Area.CityId = City.CityId
      Join State on Area.StateId = State.StateId
      join Country on Area.CountryId = Country.CountryId;
```

Comment: You need the same number of columns in select as in insert.

Comment: And no VALUES when select in INSERT. I.e. do `insert into Area (col1, ...) select ...`.

Comment: insert into area (column1,column2) select forcolumn1,forcolumn2 from x
.you dont need "values" because values is from select.

Comment: Also, don't just post pure code, please try to explain your question as well. Putting some effort into your question will make it more likely that you will receive answers :)

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of that query? You are joining target table (`Area`) with others and try to insert in it, that is a marker that data already presents in the `Area` table and you are inserting duplicates or trying to update columns which are empty now. In that case you need merge or even update.

```
UPDATE A
SET CityID = c.CityID,
    StateID = s.StateID,
    CountryID = co.CountryID
from Area a
join City c
    On a.CityId = c.CityId
Join State s 
    on a.StateId = s.StateId
join Country co
    on a.CountryId = co.CountryId;
```

If you need EXACTLY insert - specify all columns like below:

```
insert into Area Values (AreaId, AreaName, Pincode, CityId, StateId, CountryId)
select  a.AreaID,
        a.AreaName,
        a.Pincode,
        c.CityID,
        s.StateID,
        co.CountryID
from Area a
join City c
    On a.CityId = c.CityId
Join State s 
    on a.StateId = s.StateId
join Country co
    on a.CountryId = co.CountryId;
```

**Edit:**

```
insert into Area Values (AreaId, AreaName, Pincode, CityId, StateId, CountryId)
select  a.AreaID,
        a.AreaName,
        a.Pincode,
        c.CityID,
        s.StateID,
        co.CountryID
from Area a
LEFT join City c
    On c.CityName = @CityName
LEFT Join State s 
    on s.StateName = @StateName
LEFT join Country co
    on co.CountryName = @CountryName;
```

Where `@CityName`, `@StateName`, `@CountryName` are variables storing data from dropdown lists.

Comment: hi thanks for your reply. actually my CityId In City Table is associated with CityName and Cityname was in dropdownlist1,  StateId In State Table is associated with StateName and Statename was in dropdownlist2,  CountryId In Country Table is associated with CountryName and Countryname was in dropdownlist3 in Area execution page.

Comment: Area output page  AreaId, AreaName, Pincode, CityName(dropdownlist1), StateName(dropdownlist2), CountryName(dropdownlist3); City Table (CityID, CityName); State Table (StateID, StateName);Country Table (CountryID, CountryName);                                                       Area Table (AreaId, AreaName, Pincode, CityId, StataId, CountryId)

Comment: `dropdownlist2`? It is an Access form? ASP.NET? What data is stored in `Area` table? I guess you have some `AreaID, AreaName, PinCode` and try to update `CityID, StateID, CountryID`, am I right?

Comment: dropdownlist2, asp.net;  area table consists of (areaid, areaname, pincode, cityid, stateid, countryid) but area output  consists of (areaid, areaname, pincode, cityname(ddl), statename(ddl), countryname(ddl))

Comment: Look, you got a form, with some dropdowns, and you use it to add data to your `Area` table? I completely dont understand what are you triying to achieve.

Comment: City table consists of (CityId, CityName);  Area form output consists of (CityName(dropdoenlist)); Area table consists of (CityId);  finally i want to save CityName  from Dropdownlist into Area table with the help of CityId in (AREA AND CITY)

Comment: You can put values from dropdown lists to variables and use query like I add to my answer.

Comment: Hi thanks,   Am redeveloping windows application to web so can't change those thing